# Laravel Artisan CLI: How to include namespace with make command?

Tags: php, laravel

Using Laravel 5.1, I am trying to run a command like

```
php artisan make:controller Auctions\AuctionController
```

My expectation is that it would create the `AuctionController.php` file in the `app/Http/controllers/Auctions/` directory, like this:

```
app/Http/controllers/Auctions/AuctionController.php
```

However, the command created a file called `AuctionsAuctionController.php` in the `app/Http/Controllers/` directory instead:

```
app/Http/Controllers/AuctionsAuctionController.php
```

What is the correct way to reference your namespace with `make:[method]`?

Comment: I edited your question to add a small bit of explanation to draw attention to the difference between the directory + file names that you're expecting and what you actually got, with some additional [inline formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I left all the capitalization just as you had it, because I didn't know whether that might be significant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a forward slash instead of a backward slash:

```
php artisan make:controller Auctions/AuctionController
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double backslash.

```
php artisan make:controller Auctions\\AuctionController
```

In the terminal a single backslash is used to escape the following character, for example you might want a space in a file name, but obviously spaces in terminal are used to separate parameters so you can use a backslash to allow the use of a space.

For example running `touch test\ file` in the terminal will create a file called `test file`. The same applies if you want a backslash in the filename (for whatever reason), using a double backslash `touch test\\file` you'd then create a file called `test\file`